# x-www-browser GET variable

Tags: linux

I'm trying to open my default browser with my html file and a GET variable

my command line:

```
x-www-browser "index.html?var=1"
```

is openning google-chome with the url:

```
http://index.html/?var=1
```

(note: it forget the file path before index.html)

Comment: try `file://index.html` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
x-www-browser "file:///home/${USER}/index.html?var=1"
```